# Circumvent References when deleting Array Content in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference

I'm implementing a simple logging mechanism by storing arrays as log entries in a single array.
The code works like this:

```
var myarr = new Array();
var secondarr = new Array(4,5,6);
myarr.push(secondarr);
secondarr.length=0;
secondarr.push(5,5,5);
myarr.push(secondarr);
secondarr.length=0;

//check
for(var i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++){
    var str="";
    for(var j = 0; j < myarr[i].length; j++)
        str+=myarr[i][j]+" ";

    console.log(str);
}
```

I'm creating my single array `myarr`, in which logentries are stored. The `secondarr` stores data to log. Because I don't want to create a new array each time I log something into `myarr`, I wanted to set back the `secondarr` through `secondarr.length=0`.

However this deletes everything out of myarr as well, because of references!

Is there a way to circumvent creating new arrays for each log? The method of course works if I push `secondarr.slice()`, but this results in multiple arrays, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but why not simply: `myarr.push([4, 5, 6]); myarr.push([5, 5, 5]); ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace each `secondarr.length=0;` by `secondarr=[];`. The first instruction modifies the `length` property of the array referenced by `secondarr`. The second one makes that `secondarr` now refers to a new empty array.

In any case, you have to create a new array for each logentry you want to store.